# Image Url using Eval with two parameters

Tags: asp.net, eval, imageurl

Image control with the ImageUrl bound from DataSource1.

```
<asp:Image ID="image" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("CandidateId", "Picture") %>' />
```

Below is the DataSource1, brings the Picture field. But the Picture field in the database does not have the full path. It keeps the part of it like: `pictures/1250/candidatepicture.jpg`. Full path is sth like: `http://abc.storage/pictures/1250/candidatepicture.jpg`.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="DataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MyConnectionString %>"
 ProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient" SelectCommand="SELECT CandidateId, Picture, Name FROM [Candidates] WHERE ([CandidateId] = @CandidateId)">
 <SelectParameters>
      <asp:Parameter Name="CandidateId" Type="Int32" />
 </SelectParameters>
```

So when I am using Eval, I need to do sth like `ImageUrl='<%# Eval("CandidateId", "http://abc.storage/" + "Picture") %>'`. But obviously this does not work.

What's the way to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this form `Eval` accepts name of the column you need to retrieve and, optionally, the format of the resulting string. If you need to get two fields out of current data item - you need two `Eval` calls for this. However in your case one column `Picture` seems to suffice:

```
ImageUrl='<%# string.Format("http://abc.storage/{0}", Eval("Picture")) %>'
```